# Chrome disable apps icon linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am attempting to set up a pre-built chrome browser. I need to disable to the "apps" icon in the bookmarks bar before it ships. That way when the user opens it they won't see the icon.

How can I update this in the file chrome file system i.e. in `$CHROMEHOME/.config/google-chrome`. This is running on debian.

I've checked `Default/Preferences` and cannot seem to find any difference when it is enabled or disabled. I've also done a diff on the entire folder when it is enabled/disabled and cannot find anything obvious.

Comment: Disabling is usually by right-click of the Bookmarks bar and un-check of “Show apps shortcut”. See also `chrome://flags/#app-management`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that the user could remove the "Apps" icon themselves after the browser first launches, however I wanted to set it so that the icon doesn't appear in the first place. The chrome flag didn't seem to do anything when I set that to "disabled"

Answer (score 0):

In chrome policies `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/policies.json` I set `ShowAppsShortcutInBookmarkBar=false`

This prevented it from showing.